load_workbook get wrong number decimal with data_only=True
I have a file excel in A1 cell there is the formula:
sum(A2:A5)
if the sum is 100000000.01 then WS['A1'].value=100000000.0
if the sum is 99999999.01 then WS['A1'].value=99999999.01

Why?
There is a solution ?
Thanks

If the sum is 100000000.01 then WS['A1'].value=100000000.01

Arithmetic precision is limited in Excel. This is one of the many reasons why the file format is not suited for scientific work. It's convenient for reports and some tasks but useless for anything serious.
